# saves System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText instead of textbox's value asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a web form,asp.net, to save specific information into my local database in Visual Studio. Some of this web form components are html components. 
After clicking an "add" button, which is as asp.net button, the data is saved successfully into the database, but when I look to my database table, it shows me "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText" in some fields as shown in the picture below:

[image]

What confuses me is that I don't know why some values are saves correctly and the others not ! the eventName, EventDuration, EventAdmission, EventWebsite and EventVenue are all html textboxes .. and as seen in the image above for all of these fields the saved value is "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText" while the EventVenue value is saved correctly!! even though the codes are the same .. see the example below:

```
<div class="6u$ 12u$(small)">
                                                <label for="website">Website</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="website" name="website" runat="server" />

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="6u$ 12u$(small)">
                                                <label for="venue">Venue</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="venue" name="venue" runat="server" />
```

And here is my source code:

```
 protected void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string latitude = "";
        string longitude = "";
        string imagesArr = null;
        bool fields = false;
        string eventname = Request.Form["name"].ToString();
        string disc = Request.Form["TextArea3"].ToString();

        string startDate = DropDownList1.Text + "/" + category.Value + "/" + DropDownList2.Text;
        string endDate = DropDownList4.Text + "/" + days.Value + "/" + DropDownList5.Text;

        string eventduration = Request.Form["duration"].ToString()
        string eventadmission = admission.Value;
        string categ = DropDownList3.Text;
        string contact = Request.Form["TextArea4"].ToString();
        string eventwebsite = website.Value;
        string location = venue.Value;
        country.Disabled = true;
        string eventcountry = Request.Form["country"].ToString();


        if (Session["Latitude"].ToString() == null && Session["Longitude"].ToString() == null)
        {
            latitude = "";
            longitude = "";
        }
        else if (Session["Latitude"].ToString() != null && Session["Longitude"].ToString() != null)
        {
            latitude = Session["Latitude"].ToString();
            longitude = Session["Longitude"].ToString();
        }

        if (Session["ImagesArray"].ToString() != null)
        {
            imagesArr = Session["ImagesArray"].ToString();
        }



        if (DropDownList2.Text.Equals("Year") || DropDownList1.Text.Equals("Month") || category.Value.Equals("Day") || DropDownList5.Text.Equals("Year") || DropDownList4.Text.Equals("Month") || days.Value.Equals("Day") || name == null || disc == null || duration == null || admission == null || categ == null || contact == null || website == null || location == null)
        {
            fields = true;
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert(' Make sure to enter all the required data')", true);
        }
        else { fields = false; }

        if (fields == false)
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EventsEnglish(EventName,EventDescription,EventStartDate,EventEndDate,EventDuration, EventAdmission, EventCategory, EventContact, EventWebsite, EventVenue, EventMapLatitude, EventMapLongitude, CountryName, EventImages) values(N'" + name + "', N'" + disc + "',N'" + startDate + "',N'" + endDate + "',N'" + duration + "',N'" + admission + "', N'" + categ + "',  N'" + contact + "',  N'" + website + "',  N'" + location + "',  N'" + latitude + "',  N'" + longitude + "',  N'" + country + "',  N'" + imagesArr + "')";
            //command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert(' New event has been added')", true);

                name.Value = "";
                TextArea3.InnerText = "";
                DropDownList1.Text = "Month";
                category.Value = "Day";
                DropDownList2.Text = "Year";
                DropDownList4.Text = "Month";
                days.Value = "Day";
                DropDownList5.Text = "Year";
                duration.Value= "";
                admission.Value = "";
                DropDownList3.Text = "Category";
                TextArea4.InnerText = "";
                website.Value = "";
                venue.Value = "";

                Session.Remove("ImagesArray");
                Session.Remove("Latitude");
                Session.Remove("Longitude");


            }
            con.Close();
        }


    }
```

As seen in the codes above, I've used two different ways to get the value of an html text box value, such as "Request.Form["name"].ToString();" and "name.Value;" and none of them worked, except that the second way has worked for "Venue" field only.

Do you have any idea to solve this???

Comment: Try removing `runat="server"` from html code and use `value` property to get text. `Request.Form["<name>"]` shall read value from DOM textboxes.

Comment: If I remove the runat="server", then the source code doesn't recognize the html text box, it cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've figured out my issue .. in this code

```
 command.CommandText = 
    "INSERT INTO EventsEnglish( " +
        "EventName, EventDescription, EventStartDate, EventEndDate, " +
        "EventDuration, EventAdmission, EventCategory, EventContact, " +
        "EventWebsite, EventVenue, EventMapLatitude, EventMapLongitude, " +
        "CountryName, EventImages) " +
    "VALUES (" +
        "N'" + name + "', N'" + disc + "', N'" + startDate + "', " +
        "N'" + endDate + "',N'" + duration + "',N'" + admission + "', " +
        "N'" + categ + "',  N'" + contact + "',  N'" + website + "',  " +
        "N'" + location + "',  N'" + latitude + "',  N'" + longitude + "', " +
        "N'" + country + "',  N'" + imagesArr + "')";
```

I just had to add the `string local variables` instead of the `html text` boxes names .. I don't know how i didn't notice this!!